# how the linker find the right file to use it's function declaration?

Tags: c++, linker, prototype, declaration

In a simple program that use a function doSomething() to print out a "hello, world". I only typed a prototype of this function in the main.cpp file and the declaration for this function in another file named do.cpp.

when I compile the program it run properly even though I did not specify which file the declaration of the doSomething() will be.

Comment: You wrote a "declaration" in main.cpp, and a "definition" in do.cpp.

Comment: yes. and the question is how the linker used the function definition which is inside the do.cpp . and did not use another function(doSomething) that located in an other file .

Comment: @AbdessamadBond: the function definition must be unique.  If the linker finds two matches that collide, it will produce an error (something like "multiple definitions for symbol ...").  Since the names are unique, it can build a global table for the entire program (e.g. all "translation units") and find the definition in *any* source file.

Comment: Does your program actually call doSomething?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be some confusion in your idea of function *declaration* and *definition*.
The declaration of the function is the prototype of the function.
For Ex:

```
void doSomething();
```

While, the definition is the body of the function.
For Ex:

```
 void doSomething()
 {
 }
```

Usually, the declaration goes in the header file and the definition in the cpp file.

The compiler uses the declaration to match the parameters of the function being called, while the linker links the definition to the function being called.

Compilation is the process where source files are compiled in to object files.
While during linking all the object files are used by the linker to produce the executable. linker has access to different object files and hence the definition of the function defined in other file.As long as the function name is unique, the linker will happily link to that particular definition, in case linker finds more than two matches then your program breaks the **[One definition rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule)** and will report multiple definition errors.

Also, note that the linker needs to use(link) the function definition only if the function is being called, if your program just declares a function, does not provide a definition and never uses(calls) the function there will not be any errors.

Comment: Unless I completely misread the question, I don't think that you answered the question that was asked.

Comment: I understand now,I was using an IDE so without I specified that I want to link do.cpp and main.cpp together. I guess that the IDE figuered out which file to link with the main . which I still dont know how.

Comment: @AbdessamadBond: You probably just added files to the IDE, note that the IDE creates a project by default and generates an exe for your project.Unless it does that it won't be able to compile and link those multiple files together would it?

Answer (score 0):

The linker will simply consider all the files you're linking against when looking for the definition of the function.

It is not possible to link against multiple object files that define a function of the same name, so there's no ambiguity.